# EF Core - How to configure a Parent-Child Relation using Relationship table

Tags: entity-framework-core, .net-7.0

I'm trying to configure a Parent-Child relation using the Relationship table.

Within the system, there is an `Entity` class that has the capability to function both as a Parent and a Child.

```cs
public class Entity
{
   
    [Required, StringLength(30)]
    public string EntityName { get; set; }
    
    // Some other properties

    [InverseProperty("ParentEntity")]
    public virtual RelationshipManger ParentRelation { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("ChildEntity")]
    public virtual ICollection<RelationshipManger> ChildRelations { get; set; }
}
```

The Relationship table is defined below

```cs
public class RelationshipManger
{
    [Required, ForeignKey(nameof(ParentEntity))]
    public int ParentEntityId { get; set; }

    public Entity ParentEntity { get; set; }


    [Required, ForeignKey(nameof(ChildEntity))]
    public int ChildEntityId { get; set; }

    public Entity ChildEntity { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string RelationshipType { get; set; }
}
```

- An `Entity` Record may have zero/null or one Parent record.
- An `Entity` Record may have zero or multiple Child records.
- Moreover, the `RelationshipManager` Table should allow the same `ParentEntityId` to be associated with multiple `ChildEntityIds`.

I tried below configuration but it does not work.

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<RelationshipManger>(entity =>
            {
                entity.HasOne(r => r.ParentBusinessEntity)
                    .WithMany(b => b.ChildRelations)
                    .HasForeignKey(r => r.ParentBusinessEntityId)
                    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
            });
```

How to correctly configure this relation using Code First Approach? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks